# Why won't this function work?

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to C, and don't get why the first function works but not the second.

1st:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char charTest[80] = "this is a test";
    char *test = &charTest;
    strcpy(test, "one");

    printf("%s", test);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

2nd:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *test;
    test = malloc(80);
    strcpy(test, "one");

    printf("%s", test);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why?
Thank you ;) :) .

Comment: In what way does it *not work*?

Comment: That first function has some funny business in it too - are you sure it works?  It certainly shouldn't compile without warnings.

Comment: ...did you get those backward?  Every indication of C I have tells me the second will almost work, but not the first, but you indicated the opposite.  I can provide a detailed answer about pointers in C, but if it's not what you're looking for I'd rather not.

Comment: @Seth: Incorrect answer flood, actually

Comment: they both worked for me (with #include's added, of course) -- and the first had compilation warnings

Comment: @KendallFrey mine was only bad reading :(

Answer (score 1):

The first example should not compile, as you are trying to use `&charTest` which is of type `char (*)[80]` to initialize a `char*`. You probably meant:

```
char *test = &charTest[0];
```

or alternatively:

```
char *test = charTest;
```

In the second case, when you use the name of the array as an *rvalue-expression*, it *decays* into a pointer to the first element. That is, the compiler will implicitly translate it to the more explicit version: `&charTest[0]`.

The second example compiles only in C, if you are working in C, you should ask C questions and don't tag them with C++. In C++ it is an error as you need an explicit cast to turn the result of `malloc` (which is a `void*`) into a `char*`:

```
char * test = static_cast<char*>( malloc(80) );  // awkward C++
```

In this second program you are leaking memory (wether in C or C++). You should `free` the memory that you dynamically allocated.